# Disable cache globally .NET

Tags: .net, caching

is there a way to disable server caching globally in ASP.NET? Like by adding some sort of setting to the web.config file?

So far I've tried adding these and it didnt make a difference...

```
        <caching>
          <sqlCacheDependency enabled="false"></sqlCacheDependency>
            <outputCache enableOutputCache="false"
                enableFragmentCache="false"
                sendCacheControlHeader="false"
                omitVaryStar="false" />
        </caching>
```

Comment: Why do you want to disable it in the first place? If you tell the 'why', there might be a better solution to your problem. Because I can't imagine that the cache server itself is the problem. If you don't use it, it won't be in your way.

Comment: Basically I'm working on this website where I need to add new database content. Once that is added, it won't show up on the site until the caching ends..

Comment: The issue above is the outputCache section is not used as top-level within caching

Answer (score 14):

There is also a way of disabling this in system.webServer if you are using IIS7/7.5 or IIS Express. This will work in your main web.config file (for both webforms and mvc) and also in web.config files in subfolders, to disable it for particular areas of your application.

```
<system.webServer>
    <caching enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 4):

The OutputCacheSection section is used to configure application-scope settings, such as whether page output caching is enabled or disabled. For example, you can disable page output caching for the entire application by adding `enableOutputCache="false"` to the OutputCacheSection in your `Web.config` file. Settings in the configuration file take precedence over cache settings in individual pages, so the example setting means that output cache will not be used.

```
<system.web>
        <caching>
            <outputCache enableOutputCache="false"/>            
        </caching>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can disable output caching and session state  for the entire application by removing its modules , this can be done from web.config

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="OutputCache" type="System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule" />
  <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />
</httpModules>
```

or

add this to your page load

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

Comment: I don't have those modules on my web.config and I already tried adding Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
 to Global.asax with no luck

Comment: @user441365 - Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache) require to add at page level not in global.asax

Answer (score -1):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178606.aspx):

> you can disable page output caching for the entire application by adding enableOutputCache="false" to the OutputCacheSection in your Web.config file.

e.g.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <caching>
            <outputCacheSettings enableOutputCache="false"/>
        </caching>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**So your configuration is not working because you have the `enableOutputCache` attribute on the `outputCache` element, when it should be on the `outputCacheSettings` element.**

Comment: It gives me a message: The attribute enableOutputCache is not declared

Comment: Ah, 3.5 ok.  Yes, you're right, it seems to have migrated from outputCache to outputCacheSettings between 3.5 and 4 - man the web.config schema is a horrible mess! In that case your original should have worked.  One possibility - what webserver are you using (vs dev? IIS? what version?)

Comment: I'm running in Debug yes and it is still caching

Comment: Actually the MSDN link reference shows that the code in this answer is wrong, the text above the code is correct.