# Disabling Output caching through web.config

Tags: asp.net, wcf, outputcache

I am trying to neatly disable output caching for WCF application.  enableOutputCache attribute does not work for some reason, can someone explain the reason, or suggest a work around.

```
<system.web>      
    <caching>
      <outputCache enableOutputCache="false" enableFragmentCache="false"></outputCache>
      <outputCacheSettings>        
        <outputCacheProfiles>          

        </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
  </system.web>
```

Thanks

Comment: It is allready answered before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550242/disable-cache-globally-net

Comment: do you want to disable cache for WCF Services or whole site ?

Comment: @Waqar Janjua I want to disable caching for one of WCF applications

Comment: @athoik I read it, answers does not work for me

Comment: @Costa are you using OutputCache in that WCF Application ? if yes then please tell how are you using that show your code

Comment: @Costa do you read this part? **So your configuration is not working because you have the enableOutputCache attribute on the outputCache element, when it should be on the outputCacheSettings element.**

Comment: @Waqar Janjua

Yes, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/28/integrating-asp-net-output-caching-with-wcf-webhttp-services.aspx ... google to find many other articles

Comment: @athoik I tried it on both outputCacheSettings and outputCache elements, and I think it should be outputCache

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I'd like to give my two cents. I actually needed to disable caching of webapi services that are called by a SPA, and on some versions of IE they where cached by default unless the cache-control:no-cache and similar headers where present. What I did to enable browser caching of static resources and disable it for all the services was add the headers depending on the location using the web-config.

i.e.

```
<location path="api">
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
      <add name="Expires" value="-1" />
      <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```