# How can I prevent Browser Caching across all pages in Asp.Net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net

I want to disable caching throughout the application so that browsers can not cache any pages and User should not be able to view any page after logout from the application any how.

Comment: What did your research show you?

Comment: Duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914027/disabling-browser-caching-for-all-browsers-from-asp-net  ?

Comment: I'm trying from last 4 days,but didn't get any solution

Comment: try this code mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550242/disable-cache-globally-net